# Using $compile in a directive inside an ng-if

Tags: angularjs, directive, angular-ng-if

I am trying to add validation dynamically to an input, with the intent of having the controller store each of the input's validation types and error messages. It is working, but not when the form is in an ng-if that is only set to true once an async call returns.

Here is a trimmed down example of it not working: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/aeZJXqtwVs85nPE1Pn2T?p=preview

If you remove the ng-if from the containing div, validation starts to work and the input is populated with the data that is set in the async call. With the ng-if, text isn't populated and validation never fires.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-if="name">
      <form name="demoForm">
        <input type="text" 
               name="password" 
               ng-model='name' 
               add-min-length 
               ng-maxlength='15' 
               required/>

        <div ng-messages='demoForm.password.$error'>
          <div ng-message='required'>required</div>
          <div ng-message='minlength'>min length</div>
          <div ng-message='maxlength'>max length</div>
        </div>
      </form>  
    </div>
</body>
```

Remove ng-if="name" and it starts to work.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.name = 'Thing';  
  }, 1000);
});

app.directive('addMinLength', function($compile){
    return{
        priority: 1001,
        terminal: true,
        compile: function(el){
            el.removeAttr('add-min-length')
            el.attr('ng-minlength', '5');

            var fn =  $compile(el);
            return function(scope){
              fn(scope);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Does anyone have an explanation of why this might be?

I have read https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/angular/ng-if$20directive/angular/Vjo4HZ2bW1A/vKWf-m6BKMkJ
and it seems the issue might be similar, but not quite what I need.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I got a response about this from the angularjs google group that i also asked this question on.
Compile is slow and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary. The gain i thought i was getting by using built in validators was not worth the work compile costs. Adding all the validators as custom ones in the link function of my directive avoids the need for compile, and is far less convoluted.

Comment: Answered in the comment above. The answer i got was: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/9ogTKIGhcI8